# ngx-image-cropper IE-11 not working angular 7.2

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, frontend, internet-explorer-11

We are facing very unique issue in which Cropper is not working in IE 11 browser environment,
some time out of stack space is coming ,some time no errors come but cropper also does not generated.[image]
Screenshot attached of how its looking in IE11 this is the screen after selecting the image to upload.

FOR REF: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper this is the link in which you can find pollyfill for IE we have used with the pollyfill  given by angular https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

The "Out of Stack Space" error in your JavaScript programming language is generally referred to as stack overflow. When you are using JavaScript the functions it uses are copied into the memory. The memory on the JavaScript is called the "stack." If the function you are using is stacked and the script needs another function, they are both stacked together. This exceeds the stack limit and causes the "Out of Stack Space" error.

You can refer steps below may help to fix this error.

Step 1:

Open the JavaScript in your Document Object Model program. Check your script for an "infinity looping" function. When a function calls itself, the function will use conditional statements to make sure that the function never loops over itself.

Step 2:

Check your script for two functions that are calling on each other to form the infinity loop. You may have three or more infinity loops in your script. Use conditional statements to guard your code against the loop.

Step 3:

Check your script for high levels of recursive functions. A recursive function is a function that repeats back to a former part of the script. If you don't have your recursive functions in line, you could start an infinite loop back and forth, causing the "Out of Stack Space" error.

Step 4:

Build your very own stack, so you know there are no infinity loops in the code. Open your Document Object Model and start writing the script. Keep your counter variables throughout the script so you know there is no infinity looping throughout the code.

For information, you can refer this link.

[How to Repair the Error "Javascript Is Out of Stack Space"](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-repair-the-error-javascript-is-out-of-stack-space-for-free)

If this error is coming from the polyfill and you are not able to fix it by referring the above steps then I suggest you to provide feedback to the developer of that polyfill.